# (Consecutive) days label doesn't appear to be translated on ru.SO

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

On ru.SO, the (consecutive) days label isn't translated:

> [image]

<sub>I have problems with flash, so freehand will be added a bit later, sorry :(</sub>